# Не работает форма на php mail()

Tags: php, email, form, phpmailer

Не работает отправка почты
Пишет, что выполнилось, но писем нет. Почта доменная, php mail на хостинге включен

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "hello@domain.ru"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, куда будут приходить письма
    $from = "no-reply@domain.ru"; //
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Форма отправки сообщений с сайта";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = "ФИО посетителя: ". $name . " | Телефон "  . $_POST['sub'] . " | Комментарий: " . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   // mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender - Отключено!
    echo "Сообщение отправлено. Спасибо Вам " . $name . ", мы скоро свяжемся с Вами.";
    echo "<br /><br /><a href=''>Вернуться на сайт.</a>";

}
```

**html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input name="name" placeholder="Укажите Ваше имя*" class="textbox" required />
   <input name="sub" placeholder="Укажите Ваш номер телефона*" class="textbox" required />
   <!--<input name="email" placeholder="Укажите ваш Email!" class="textbox" type="email" required />-->
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" placeholder="Введите Ваше сообщение:" class="message" ></textarea>
   <input name="submit" class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: Для начала стоит проверить возвращаемое значение функции `mail`. А потом видно будет

Comment: Смотрите логи или нам за вас надо к вам телепатически зайти и глянуть?

Comment: Если `true`, то проблема в настройках почтовика. Либо вы неверные данные указываете во `$from` (невалидный почтовый ящик)